# How to debug TLS communication between an ESP8266 and MQTT broker (selfsigned credentials)?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, esp8266, mosquitto, arduino-ide

I am trying to get an Wemos D1 mini (ESP8266) communicate with a MQTT broker using TLS (garagedoor opener), but failing. I get it to work when testing using MQTT.fx, tho....

I am a first offender, but I have used my google-fu to capacity. Still don't get it.
I have looked at https://nofurtherquestions.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/making-an-esp8266-web-accessible/ quite a bit. Also https://myles.eftos.id.au/blog/2016/09/14/so-the-esp8266-does-support-tlsv1-2/#.WptU5-jOXDc saw some traffic.

There are a few somewhat similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736158/ssl-certificate-verification-on-esp8266-wemos-d1-mini-with-mqtt-broker), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030019/mqtt-between-esp8266-and-arduino-with-pubsubclient) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436185/why-is-this-mqtt-client-example-failing), but since they don't deal with TLS it isn't that much help to me.

Also, I am an amateur coder/DIYer so code structure and knowledge might be lacking....anyway....

I have combined the client certificate and key files (produced by using openssl) into certificate.h:

```
$ xxd -i client.crt client_bin.crt
$ xxd -i client.key client_bin.key
$ cat client.* > certificate.h
```

My sketch:

```
// ------------- Includes ---------------
#include <certificate.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
// ------------- Wifi -------------------
const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "password";
// ------------- MQTT -------------------
const char* mqttServer = "mqtt.ranheim3r.com";
const int mqttPort = 8883;
const char* mqttTopic = "garagedoor";
const char* mqttUser = "test";
const char* mqttPassword = "1234";
// =====================================

// Set up secure comms
WiFiClientSecure espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {
  // Set up serial for debug
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Connect to Wifi
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  espClient.setCertificate(client_crt, client_crt_len);
  espClient.setPrivateKey(client_key, client_key_len);

  client.setServer(mqttServer, mqttPort);
  client.setCallback(callback);

  // Init future I/O
}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect("ESPclient", mqttUser, mqttPassword)) {
      Serial.println("connected to Mqtt broker");
      client.subscribe(mqttTopic);
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Connect/Reconnect to mqtt broker & subscribe
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();
  // Act on messages
} 

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Activate the door (Test using BUILTIN_LED) if an 1 was received as first character
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
    // but actually the LED is on; this is because
    // it is acive low on the ESP-01)
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite (BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);
  } else {
    // Then nothing...
  }
}
```

This yields the follwoing result from mosquitto:

```
1520115630: mosquitto version 1.4.10 (build date Mon, 29 May 2017 13:43:29 +0100) starting
1520115630: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mosquitto.conf.
1520115630: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1520115630: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1520115632: New connection from 192.168.1.170 on port 8883.
1520115632: OpenSSL Error: error:1417C0C7:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate
1520115632: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1520115637: New connection from 192.168.1.170 on port 8883.
1520115637: OpenSSL Error: error:1417C0C7:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate
1520115637: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

....and serial output, mirroring that:

```
WiFi connected
IP address: 
192.168.1.170
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
```

My MQTT.fx config:

```
{
  "connectionProfiles" : [ {
    "recentSubscriptionTopics" : [ ],
    "recentPublishTopics" : [ ],
    "preDefinedMessages" : [ ],
    "brokerAddress" : "mqtt.ranheim3r.com",
    "brokerPort" : "8883",
    "lastPublishTopic" : null,
    "lastSubscriptionTopic" : null,
    "profileName" : "local mosquitto",
    "profileType" : "MQTT_BROKER",
    "scriptsPath" : "",
    "connectionOptions" : {
      "clientId" : "paho60251542020336",
      "connectionTimeout" : 30,
      "keepAliveInterval" : 60,
      "mqttVersionUseDefault" : true,
      "mqttVersion" : "3.1.1",
      "cleanSession" : true,
      "automaticReconnect" : true,
      "maxInflight" : 10,
      "userName" : "test",
      "password" : "1234",
      "lwtQos" : 0,
      "lwtRetained" : false,
      "lastWillDestination" : "",
      "testament" : "",
      "useProxy" : false,
      "useHttpsProxy" : false,
      "httpsProxyHost" : "",
      "httpsProxyPort" : "",
      "httpProxyHost" : "",
      "httpProxyPort" : "",
      "httpProxyUser" : "",
      "httpProxyPassword" : "",
      "httpProxyHeaderUserAgent" : "defaultClient",
      "enableSSLTLS" : true,
      "sslTlsProtocol" : "TLSv1.1",
      "certificateFilesPemFormat" : true,
      "selfCreatedCaFile" : "C:\\ca.crt",
      "caFile" : "C:\\ca.crt",
      "clientCertificateFile" : "C:\\client2.crt",
      "clientKeyFile" : "C:\\client2.key",
      "clientKeyPassword" : "",
      "useSelfCreatedCA" : false,
      "useServerSignedCertificate" : false,
      "useTrustedKeystoreFile" : false,
      "useCertificateFiles" : true,
      "useKeystoreFiles" : false,
      "clientKeystoreFilesPemFormat" : false,
      "trustedKeystoreOnlyFile" : "",
      "trustedKeystoreOnlyPassword" : "",
      "trustedKeystoreFile" : "C:\\jssecacerts",
      "trustedKeystoreAlias" : "192.168.1.68",
      "trustedKeystorePassword" : "",
      "clientKeystoreFile" : "",
      "clientKeystorePassword" : "",
      "clientKeyPairAlias" : "",
      "clientKeyPairPassword" : ""
    },
    "notificatonsEnabled" : false,
    "showLastestMessagesOnly" : false,
    "lastSelectedPayloadDecoderId" : "plain_text_decoder",
    "googleCloudIotOptions" : {
      "projectId" : "ENTER-YOUR-IOT-PROJECT-ID",
      "registryId" : "ENTER-YOUR-REGISTRY-ID",
      "deviceId" : "ENTER-YOUR-DEVICE-ID",
      "cloudRegion" : "us-central1",
      "privateKeyFile" : "rsa_private_pkcs8",
      "algorithm" : "RS256",
      "mqttBridgeHostname" : "mqtt.googleapis.com",
      "mqttBridgePort" : 443
    }
  } ]
}
```

At this point, I am at a loss where to look, to be honest.

1. I assume it suffices to put forward client certificate and key (signed by the same CA that signed server cert/key) without the use of the ca.crt?
2. Is there a way to signal the use of, say, TLS1.1...and if so, is it needed? (I have tried changing it at the broker, but that didn't help)
3. If the MQTT.fx client is able to connect using the same credentials, am I (in the ESP8266 case) putting the information forward at the wrong time, or could it be the wrong information?
4. How would you go about debugging this?

Thanks for your time,

Greger

Comment: I'd start with using something like wireshark to see exactly what is being sent over the air

Comment: Thanks!
I did get WS and I am trying to familiar with it atm.

Comment: Did you end up fixing it? I would be interested in your explanation.